# removing headers and footers in android webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to load a responsive webpage in a webview component. But I would like to strip the header and footer of the webpage and load the webview with just the body of the webpage. How can this be achieved in an android webview.

```
<div class="header-container">
<header class="header clearfix" ng-include="'/modules/core/homepage/header-partial.html'"></header>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the header/footer look like in HTML?

Comment: I have added the header div to the original post . The use case is we are trying to create an app which would display some contents from an existing responsive website , but just want to display the body of the html page and strip off the header and footer before displaying it on a webview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to remove the header and footer and  load the webpage using loadDataWithBaseURL() method

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(mUrl).get();
document.getElementsByClass("header-container").remove();
document.getElementsByClass("footer").remove();
WebSettings ws = mWebView.getSettings();
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//mWebView.loadData(document.toString(),"text/html","utf-8");
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(mUrl,document.toString(),"text/html","utf-8","");
```

As per the developer docs :

Note that JavaScript's same origin policy means that script running in a page loaded using this method will be unable to access content loaded using any scheme other than 'data', including 'http(s)'. To avoid this restriction, use loadDataWithBaseURL() with an appropriate base URL.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit html, i'd recommend using a html parser like jsoup. Them remove header and footer, and lastly load the data into a `WebView`

```
try {

    // Load the html into jsoup
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://your-site.com/").get();

    // find and remove header
    Element header = doc.getElementById("your-header");
    header.remove();

    // find and remove footer
    Element footer = doc.getElementById("your-footer");
    footer.remove();

    // Load data into a WebView
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadData(doc.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had tried earlier. I am able to load the website using  webview.loadUrl() but the above approach doesn't load the contents of the websites event without removing the header and footers