# Android WebView remove header and footer

Tags: android

I used this code and working but it first loads with website header and then afterward loads without header.
What is wrong in this code? What to modify so that only one screen loads, i.e, without website header?

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];"
                + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                "})()");

        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];"
                + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                "})()");
    }
});

webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925677/removing-headers-and-footers-in-android-webview/29928497#29928497) can solve your issue.

Comment: well you could set its display none and when loaded set display block

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by putting this code in `OnLoadResource()` method instead of `OnPageFinished()` and using `evaluateJavascript`:

```
override fun onLoadResource(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:(function() { " +
                "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];"
                + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                "})()", {});
    }
```