# CSS with ID selector is not loading on android Webview

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I'm trying to load html with CSS which has ID selector and the file doesn't load to the webview as expected.

This is the file which I tried to load:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <head>
        <style>
           #para1 {
              text-align: center;
              color: red;
                   }
              </style>
              </head>
            <body>
        <p id="para1">Hello World!</p>
        <p>This paragraph is not affected by the style.</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

However when I tried the code below,it loads to the webview.

```
         <html>
            <head>
              <style>
                h1 {color:red;}
                p {color:blue;}
             </style>
             </head>
              <body>
             <h1>A heading</h1>
             <p>A paragraph.</p>
          </body>
         </html>
```

I have enabled these properties on the WebView:

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); // ZoomControls
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // Multitouch
    mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(CONFIG.webviewEnableViewport());
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Some info about the header in WebView on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925677/removing-headers-and-footers-in-android-webview/29928497#29928497)

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? For me it works exactly as I would expect it to work. `not working` is a quite useless description for us. you need to be way more clear then that. What is not working? what is expected? what result do you get?

Comment: @tacoshy I'm getting blank page for the first snippet

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue by using the base64 encoding.

```
   String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(myHtmlString.getBytes(), 
   Base64.NO_PADDING);
   mWebView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64");
```